# Android Jsoup can't get inner text

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to get a value inside the Tag label id="spanRate" 4.0599

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

```
<div class="form-group blueRow" id="div_rate" name="div_rate">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-xs-7">Best Available Exchange Rate Online</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <label id="spanRate">4.0599</label> HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it returns empty...

```
   Elements dayRate = document.select("label#spanRate");
   System.out.println("dayRate : " + dayRate); // return: <label id="spanRate"></label> // NOTHING BETWEEN TAGS
   System.out.println("dayRate : " + dayRate.text()); // return: NOTHING
   System.out.println(document.select("div.col-xs-5 label").text()); // NOTHING
```

I have seem similar questions here, as it said it's duplicate; but that didn't answer my question! I made a few typo mistakes before but that wasn't the issue... "<"label id='spanRate'>"4.0599"<"/label">" returns: "<"label id='spanRate'>""<"/label">"... Could it be because it's content has been added to the DOM by Javascript after the page load? and therefore it's invisible to Jsoup? Is there a way around it? Thank you

Comment: `System.out.println(document.select("div.col-xs-5 label").text());`

Comment: Why not just the simple select statement above? (corrected)

Comment: You look to be forgetting to call the `text()` method of Elements.

Comment: `TestFour.text()` would work too.

Comment: It's just a typo. `div.col-sx-5` -> `div.col-xs-5` `div.col-sx-7` -> `div.col-xs-7`

Comment: Thank you for looking into this I fix the typo but still not getting the inner text I want; it seems that it's getting a different portion of the html somewhere else:

Comment: @Hovercraft TestFour with .Text() return Nothing as without .text() return <label id="spanRate"></label>... so inside the tags there's no text...